# Finding the derivative for the following functions

Tags: derivatives

Question:Using the rules of finding derivatives, find the derivative $f’$ of the following functions:

(a)  $f(x) = 2x +8$

(b) $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2$

(c)  $f(x) = 120$

**My answer**
I used rules and my answer are these.Does anybody have any comment about my answer?

(a) $f'(x)=2$

(b) $f'(x)=b+2cx$

(c) $f'(x)=0$

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Well done ! Congratulations. Just continue that way. Cheers.